# Why wasn't <form> inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, browser

A simple example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="f1">
    </form>
    <script>
        $('#f1').html(
            '<div id="outer">' +
                '<form id="f2">' +
                    '<div id="inner"></div>' +
                '</form>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If we open this page in a browser, we will not see the `#f2` form.
Why does it get removed?

[image: No f2 <form> element.]

I know that nested forms are not valid according to the standard, but in the project I am working on insertion of forms inside forms sometimes works and I can't figure out the difference (in both cases forms are inserted via `.html()`).

I have also tried `innerHTML`, but the result was the same.

Comment: When your `script` will be executed?!

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui, it doesn't matter, I think. You can move it to a separate file, but it won't change anything.

Comment: Because you can't nest a form inside a form

Comment: Though you can have several <form> elements in one HTML page, you cannot nest them

Comment: As stated above, you cannot have nested `<form>` elements. The browser's HTML renderer is removing the one you attempt to append. What goal are you trying to achieve with this code? Why do you need th esecond form?

Comment: @Turnip, if we .wrap() the #inner into a <form>, it will work. So why can't we just insert it?

Comment: Why do you even try to wrap() a form into another form?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, because we now have some components based on using forms and it will take much time to rewrite them. Moreover, in more complicated structures inserting forms inside forms sometimes succeeds.

Comment: Regardless of any hacky techniques, nested forms are not valid HTML and will cause issues in your browser. You need to re-assess why you are attempting to do this and find a better solution.

Comment: @NamelessLambda, this is just a simple example to briefly demonstrate the problem. In our project the HTML hierarchy is much deeper and it does have sense to have nested forms and they really work.

Comment: If you really want to do this, it's not undefined behaviour, but it is invalid HTML and it may not work reliably cross-browser. Use at your own risk and test thoroughly. Avoid attaching the inner form to the DOM document with methods that use HTML parsing such as `innerHTML` or its jquery wrapper `.html()`. Instead, construct a sub tree containing the inner form with .innerHTML and then use DOM methods such as `appendChild()` to add that subtree as a child of the outer form.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into undefined behavior.

[Quoted from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)

> **Note:** It's strictly forbidden to nest a form inside another form. Nesting can cause forms to behave in an unpredictable manner based on the browser that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will automatically remove the nested forms from your code tyring to adjust it to meet the valid standars.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `form` inside `form` tag, try to replace outer `form` to `div`

```js
$('#f1').html(
    '<div id="outer">' +
        '<form id="f2">' +
            '<div id="inner">Inner Div</div>' +
        '</form>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="f1">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```